# VBA How to keep cell format before pasting data / Copy only Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that copies the data selected by me, but I would like to keep the cell format in the otuput file (zeszyt 3) as it was before pasting. I mean copy only Value without formats.

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)

wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("A:C").Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A1")
wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("H").Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("D1")
wb.Sheets("analityka_id-tabele").Range("E68:G71").Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("strona 3").Range("E16")
wb.Sheets("analityka_id-tabele").Range("E72:G72").Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("strona 3").Range("E15")


wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

Beep

MsgBox "Mamy to"
End Sub
```

Comment: Again: use the Sub "copyRangeValues" - it only transfers values but no format - did you ever try it? Why do you ask questions if you don't try to implement the provided solutions?

Comment: Im not sure im good undesrtood your way :( . and im really beginner and im little scare to do big changes of my code.

Comment: You can show my how to change my code for your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the "`destination:=`" command doesn't support "only values".

So I would use `.copy` and then `.pastespecial` with "`.xlPasteValues`"

**Full code tested:**

```
Sub test()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook

'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath, False, True)

wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("A:C").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("H").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Sheets("analityka_id-tabele").Range("E68:G71").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("strona 3").Range("E16").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb.Sheets("analityka_id-tabele").Range("E72:G72").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("strona 3").Range("E15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing

'Beep

MsgBox "Mamy to"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xlPasteValues`.

The general format is:

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

For example, the 3rd line in your code would go from this:

```
wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("A:C").Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("input_4").Range("A1")
```

to

```
With wb.Sheets("vintage_agr").Columns("A:C")
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```